# Reassigning variables between classes in OOP tkinter not working

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm a student messing around with some python tkinter stuff and I have noticed that my global variable isn't switching between two classes after I reassign it in one of my classes. At the top I declare a variable

```
username=""
```

Then I got a `Main` class which sorts out switching between classes or windows in this case

```
class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.geometry("500x500")

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Login, Menu, Type, Multi):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.geometry("300x250")
        self.show_frame(Login)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

Then I've got a class `Login` which I use for my login menu and once a correct login was used, which was read from a file, I attempt to reassign the `username` variable to the new username:

```
class Login(tk.Frame):
    ...
    ...
    def checkLogin(self, enteredUsername, enteredPassword, cont):

        for user in usersData:
            if user[0]==enteredUsername and user[1]==enteredPassword:
                global username
                username = enteredUsername
                cont.show_frame(Menu)
                print(username)
            else:
                incorrectLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Incorrect Login")
                incorrectLabel.place(height=20, width=85, x=100, y=175)
```

And once I try to call the `username` variable in the next class along like this:

```
class Menu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Select Game", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        typeButton = tk.Button(self, text="Type Answer", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Type), height=3, width=25)
        typeButton.pack()
        multiButton = tk.Button(self, text="Multiple Choice", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Multi), height=3, width=25)
        multiButton.pack()
        scoresButton = tk.Button(self, text="Show scores", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Multi), height=3, width=25)
        scoresButton.pack()

        usernameLabel = tk.Label(self, text=f'logged in as {username}')
        usernameLabel.pack()
```

When logged in as `username`, this doesn't work and displays just the blank variable that I declared at the start not showing the updated new one.

Comment: You seem to think that if `username` changes, so should the string that's been assigned to the label at the time the `Menu` was instantiated. That's not the case. Whenever `username` changes, you need to update the label explicitly. There is no implicit "contract" between your `username` variable and the label object.

Comment: It *is* possible to make it so that updating the value of `username` automatically updates the `Label` by making the former a [`StringVar`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112025221id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) instead of a regular string and referring to it when creating the `Label` by specifying the `textvariable=` option. See this `Label` [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/label.html).